# 2Captcha Api Cannot Set Property

Tags: javascript, c#, web

I return from the API with the code below:

```
string result = SendCaptcha(txtApiKey.Text, txtSiteKey.Text, pageurl);
Thread.Sleep(10000);
string answer = GetAnswer(result, txtApiKey.Text);
```

I'm trying to post the answer I got in this way.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('g-captcha-response').innerHTML='" + answer + "';");
```

The error I got

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to tag C# instead of C?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to tag c#.

Comment: That means it's not there. Maybe it's in a iframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem.

```
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/textarea[2]"));
        string aa = (string)js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','visibility:visible;');", element);
```

But now I have a problem.

There is no submit button on hcatpcha.

I'm looking for the CallBack method, but I couldn't find it.

As a result, I'm decoding the chaptcha but I can't post this result.